# Jquery Dialog Title bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-dialog

Below is my Jquery Dialog. When Dialog pop up, the tile bar is showing 100% as shown in image.

How do I put space after the "X" (closing button) in the title bar?

```
 $("#imgForwardProposal").click(function (e) {
            $("#divSearch").dialog({
                open: function () {
                    $(this).closest(".ui-dialog")
                    .find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close")
                    .removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close");
                },
                title: "Search Employee",
                show: "scale",
                modal: true,
                width: '55%',
                height: 500
            });
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    margin-right:20px;
}
```